# disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal no effect

Tags: swift, uikit

- What I'm trying to do:

Keep the keyboard visible while transitioning to a new View Controller presented modally by

```
        let inputViewController = SimpleViewController()
        inputViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet

        self.present(inputViewController, animated: true)
```

- What I got:

The keyboard is dismissed quickly and presented again, the transition is not visually good.

- What I tried:

  - override `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` in `SimpleViewController` to return `true` according to the documentation that should be enough however is it seems is not longer the case.
  - becoming first responder in the presented view controller during the view loading with no difference.

**Edit:**
What's the effect of `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal == true` if not to keep the Keyboard on?